# Is possible find 3.0 Bluetooth devices with CoreBluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm using the example of BLEPractice in Github: [BLE Example](https://github.com/conscientiousness/BLEPractice)

But this not show in the list all bluetooth devices that I have near my iPhone. In fact only show a heartband but not show a bluetooth headsets and a selfie monopad (3.0 Bluetooth ins't 4.0).

There is any easy example to show all bluetooth devices easily?

Answer (score 4):

No.

> Communicate with Bluetooth 4.0 low-energy devices.

[Per Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth).

Comment: But it's for 4.0 devices, there are any examples for 3.0?

Comment: CoreBluetooth does not work with non BLE devices, period. That quote I have is from the top of the linked page. If you need to speak with a 3.0 Bluetooth device, than you need to join MFI (https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action) and write a check to Apple.

Comment: oh. So, couldn't exist any application to show a classic monopad selfie near your iphone?